# Strong linear independent of matrices

Tags: matrices, independence

Let $A_1,\dots, A_n$ be $n\times n$ (real) matrices.  What is a necessary and sufficient condition so that there exists a row vector $r^t\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
r^tA_1,\dots,r^tA_n
$$
are linearly independent?  I can see that linear independence of $r^tA_1,\dots,r^tA_n$ implies that $A_1,\dots, A_n$ must be linearly independent.  But this is not sufficient.  For a counter example, consider the matrices
$$
A_1=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right),\hspace{0.1in}
A_2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
-1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
Then $A_1$ and $A_2$ are linearly independent but for any row vector $r^t\in \mathbb{R}^2$, $r^tA_1$ and $r^tA_2$ are linearly dependent.  Also, requiring $A_1$ and $A_2$ to be linearly independent and have full rank is stronger than needed.  The counterexample is
$$
A_1=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right),\hspace{0.1in}
A_2=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{array}\right)
$$
Then for $r^t=(1,1)$, $r^tA_1$ and $r^tA_2$ are linearly independent.

Comment: $r^tA_1$ and $r^tA_2$ in your first example look like $[A+B,0]$ and $[A-B,0]$ and thus when you solve for their linear independence they will certainly be l.dependent, because they are multiples of one another, furthermore you have two unknowns and one equation i.e. infinitely many solutions, whereas for the second example you had a better chance of having a unique solution and in fact you did get a unique solution because the row vectors are of the form $[1,0]$ and $[0,1]$ thus you cannot have a zero component in the same entry for all the row vectors $r^tA_1,...,r^tA_n$.